# Flash based cropper like this, but with source or customizable?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, image-processing

I am looking for a Flash based image uploader with resize and possibly rotate function. 
I have checked many possibilities, and the very best in simplicity and unser experience I found is [**Kroppr**](http://kroppr.rborn.info/index.php) at a very affordable €29/license.

The downside is, it comes with encrypted PHP code to bind the product to a subdomain. That is understandable, but while I'm perfectly happy to pay money for a tool as great as that, and ready to sign all sorts of legal agreements to protect the license, I am not ready to use encrypted PHP code, especially not from an outlet that doesn't even have a postal address on its web site.

**Does anybody know an Open Source or commercial solution that comes close to Kroppr and ships with source, or allow for full customization and free definition of the server-side backend?**

The features in detail:

- Rectangular selection to **crop** image, slider or similar to **zoom**
- Optionally: **Rotating**
- "Accept" and "Reset" buttons, "accept" triggers a call to the server and submits the image
- Full visual customizability (at least background and text colours)
- Possibility to rename all controls

> **The server side technology would preferably be PHP.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these three image utilities during my search:

- [Flex Image Cropping Component](http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/)
- [HOW TO CROP AND RESIZE AN IMAGE USED AS BACKGROUND FOR CANVAS](http://www.flexer.info/2008/10/16/how-to-crop-and-resize-an-image-used-as-background-for-canvas/)
- [Building an image-viewing widget with ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/image_viewer.html)

The first one is an open source flex component using an MIT license.  The second one is a how to,with full source available.  It doesn't have a sizable box, but it seems ok otherwise.  The last one is also a how to article from adobe.com with source available.

Comment: Cheers Gabrial, I think I will try delving into Actionscript a bit, and your open source links help me with that.

Answer (score 7):

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html i love this one, every easy to use and tons of features. i know your searching a flash cropper but this question is tagged with js too so....

Comment: Cheers antpaw, JCrop is great and I may end up with using it if my attempts with the flash based solutions don't work out. For the purposes of this question, though, I'm going to go with Gabriel McAdams's open source recommendation and try to customize them to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of good javascript based croppers:

- [Yahoo! UI ImageCropper](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/index.html)
- [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)
- [MooCrop](http://www.nwhite.net/MooCrop/)
- [UvumiTools](http://tools.uvumi.com/crop.html)
- [PHP & jQuery Image Upload and Crop](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/)

Here is a list of action script based croppers:

- [Flex Image Cropping Component](http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/)
- [Image Crop](http://www.sephiroth.it/file_detail.php?pageNum_comments=10&id=109)

Comment: Thanks Gregory. Your list is great, and as I said to @antpaw above I may end up with one of the JS based ones, but I am going to go and try with the Flash based solutions first, and Gabriel pointed out some "how-to"s that serve me best for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/07/22/multiple-files-uploader-with-preview-on-client-side/

OR

http://www.resize-before-upload.com/

...took a bit of searching =)

Comment: I also like that guy's old one. It's simple...no upload bar but still nice.  http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/06/07/client-side-image-resize-flash-cs4-filereferencedata/

Comment: They both look nice but none of them does user-controlled cropping, which I need in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the free pixlr editor and their developers API : http://pixlr.com/wiki/developer

Comment: I am very wary depending on external services for an essential function. Otherwise, they would be very interesting.

Comment: i can understand that ... but it was worth the try ... i've known their system for a long time and thought they could come in handy :)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
http://matrixoft.infunity.com/agents/calvin/tmp/forPekka.html

> I'm perfectly happy to pay money for a tool as great as that

To carry out the responsibility of posting the answer for stackoverflow users, here is part of the crop image code:

```
var tNewImage:BitmapData=new BitmapData(mouseX-vCropX,mouseY-vCropY,true,0);
iImg.getChildAt(0).x = vSize/2 -vCropX;
iImg.getChildAt(0).y =  vSize/2 -vCropY;
tNewImage.draw(iImg);
```

Where **iImg** is the movieclip containing the image with the image center positioned at (0,0) , **vSize** is the image dimension, **vCropX** and **vCropY** is the top left cropping coordinate. The **tNewImage** BitmapData is used for constructing the new Cropped Bitmap image

Comment: Cheers for the offer. Well, this already looks nice, but what I need would go a bit beyond that :) I would love to have this programmed from scratch but I think that's beyond my budget no matter how fast, or cheap, a Flash developer is.

Comment: A bit beyond that.. do you mean upload to server? I can add that code too. Or do you want more?

Comment: hey hey I wanna get the bounty :D Is it just the upload function? I can add the upload function + php code and send the source code to you. Will that be good enough to be the accepted answer? If yes I will spend some time to work on it...

Comment: Sorry Unreality, I didn't see your comments. What I need is: 1. User picks file 2. Cropping but it would have to look and behave like the jquery cropper (google) 3. Zooming the image to a specified size *with the crop area visible* 4. Rotating (optional) 5. Transmission of image, crop, zoom and rotation data to server side script. BUT. While I appreciate your offer, there would be a *lot* that would have to work well and tested. It's definitely more work than this bounty is worth, and I will probably end up finding one of the commercial solutions presented here suitable for my needs.

Comment: If you really want to put something together, and if it survives my tests and requirements, and you'd publish as Open Source here, within the next days, I'll be happy to accept your solution. But I wouldn't want anybody to invest days' worth of work in this, and then not get the bounty because it didn't work for me (If I find a solution here that works for me out of the box I have to pick that, even if it took the person three minutes to Google). If it's the reputation you're after, you're better off answering other questions. But if it's for the sake of building it - you're welcome, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I've used RadActive's [I-Load](http://i-load.radactive.com/) component before, with great success. The UI customisation options are a little limited, but as far as functionality goes, I'm pretty sure it meets all your requirements.

**EDIT**: You don't specify what server-side technology you're using (if any). I'm pretty sure I-Load is designed for ASP.NET - this may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Cheers kristian: This looks great, but my server side language of choice is indeed PHP. Setting up an environment that can handle ASP .NET is too much trouble. Sorry I didn't mention that from the start.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://activeden.net/item/image-cropper-as3/74161) is also a nice once and its only $10.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

Still doesn't have image rotation/cropping. I most definitely do plan to add that, but after checking out all the things I could find I still wasn't happy. I researched out all the particulars and just ended up building my own. You're welcome to use it if you like and haven't found something else by now. Keep checking the link, I'll update it to include the rotation and crop feature along with multiple image uploads.