# Flash image upload with mandatory crop?

Tags: image, file, upload, resize, crop

Anyone know of a Flash file (image) uploader that will force a user to resize and/or crop their image BEFORE uploading it? To then upload it as well.

Basically, I don't want my server processing the image resize/crop. I want to specify a target aspect ratio and have the user resize and crop their image to make it fit.

I've seen cropping uploaders before but they all seem to be server side. I saw a Flex one but I'm not sure it's "mandatory" -- Basically if the user just uploads the image without making edits, then I'd like the Flash to scale and fit the image into set dimensions...Leaving it I guess short in one direction to not stretch.

Anything like this out there? 
Thanks!

Comment: Another idea: http://pixlr.com/wiki/developer/api
But this is too heavy duty for my needs (and probably most people's) but way cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/07/22/multiple-files-uploader-with-preview-on-client-side/

there was another one called resize before upload but the site went down. though while I'm updating this and we're on the subject -- I don't see why you'd want to use Flash these days for this task. There are plenty of JavaScript options and now we also have Google's Dart (which builds JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

I have a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974422/flash-based-cropper-like-this-but-with-source-or-customizable) running with a very similar question, be sure to take a peek - there isn't anything there yet that does client side resizing, though.

Also, [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) is said to support it in the new Beta, but the feature is very sparsely documented right now. You would probably have to work on it to get it running the way you want.

Comment: LinkedIn is probably a real good example of what I'm after. I'll check out SWFUpload again, I went there today and didn't see the feature jumping out at me. The Flex tool I found: http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/  - close but I think I'd have to get my hands dirtier than I'd like.

Comment: Must be this that you're talking about: http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta1/resizedemo/index.php

Eh, yea. I can live with that. But bonus points to being able to crop the image. Plus this apparently says to resize on client side...but I'm guessing it uploads it too then downloads back? Sounds a little silly, what if the user wanted to reject the photo? Why even bother showing the user a preview of the resized image?

Comment: Well, client side resizing is what you're after, isn't it? Cropping is a different thing, yes... I don't know of any combined cropper and client side resizer yet, although it should be perfectly possible. Maybe something turns up in the bounty, we'll see.

Comment: yea, i'll live w/o the resizing for now. when i get time in a few months i'll whip something up in actionscript to do this. i just figured by 2010 there'd have to be a few dozen (free or even pay) versions by now. i'll watch your question.