# Image uploader + crop

Tags: flash, image, upload, seam, crop

I'm running a web application built on Seam. I would like to have an image upload + crop component.Preferably on client side, so the image uploaded to the server would be the result of the crop. I read this can be made with Flash 10. I was thinking flex is also a possibility. Does anyone has good hints to give me, what component to choose or what is the best way to connect the backing bean I have with the flash/flex? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for Flash uploaders shows many:

From the StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974422/flash-based-cropper-like-this-but-with-source-or-customizable):

- [Flex Component](http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/)
- [Building an image-viewing widget with ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/image_viewer.html)
- [Another](http://www.flexer.info/2008/10/16/how-to-crop-and-resize-an-image-used-as-background-for-canvas/)
- [DeepLiquid](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)
- [MediaBlur](http://blog.mediablur.com/2008/02/20/flex-image-cropping-component/)

From the StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008836/flash-image-upload-with-mandatory-crop)

- [ResizeBeforeUpload](http://www.resize-before-upload.com)
- [AdLevy](http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/07/22/multiple-files-uploader-with-preview-on-client-side)

From Google:

- [element-it](http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx)
- [Sephiroth](http://www.sephiroth.it/file_detail.php?pageNum_comments=10&id=109)

Check those SO threads.

If you were not bound by Flash, I would recommend using Javascript instead.

In Mootools:

- Crop with the images with [CwCrop](http://mootools.net/forge/p/cwcrop)
- Upload with [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I cannot do that client side with javascript.. :/ That's why I talked about flash...

Comment: Thank you for having looked other threads here in stackoverflow. Yet, I did that too and none of the above fit the needs I described or tell me how to integrate the app I already have with the flex image upload and crop component. Most of the links above don't have the crop functionality which is a must have...

Comment: I ended up using the element-it one. Their support is just great! Thank you for the hint!